# Using the 'For' loop to fill out array

Tags: c#

So I'm almost completely a beginner & just doing practices, I'm trying to figure out how to use a for loop to create and fill out an array, using user input.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the employee's name: ");
string employeeName = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("How many months do you want to input for: ");
int arrayField = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

int[] months = new int[arrayField];

for (int i = 0; i < arrayField; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Absence for the month: ");
    months[0] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

So this obviously just copies over whatever you have for `months[0]`.
My question is, how would you write it if you wanted it to fill out every entry? (`months[1]`, `months[2]`, etc)

Comment: `month[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` `i` - i is an index incremented in every loop

Comment: Change `months[0]` to `months[i]`

Comment: christ thank you didn't realize it was that simple

Comment: @EricElliott More importantly: **Do you understand why you had to make that change**?